# Yarn scheduler queue configuration is wrong in JMX server

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have defined two node label in YARN: `stream` and `online` each of which including 3 nodes with 1024 MB RAM and 1 core. (In aggregate there are 6 nodemanager). I defined two queues, `streamQ` and `onlineQ` that are mapped to nodes with label `stream` and `online`, respectively. There is no node with `default_partition` label. So the capacity_scheduler.xml is configured:

```
<!-- configuration of queue-root -->


<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name> 
  <value>streamQ,onlineQ</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels</name> 
  <value>*</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.stream.capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.online.capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default-node-label-expression</name> 
  <value>*</value> 
</property>


 <!-- configuration of queue-streamQ -->


<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.capacity</name> 
  <value>50</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.maximum-capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.accessible-node-labels</name> 
  <value>stream</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.accessible-node-labels.stream.capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.accessible-node-labels.online.capacity</name> 
  <value>0</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.default-node-label-expression</name> 
  <value>stream</value> 
</property>


<!-- configuration of queue-streamQ -->


<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.capacity</name> 
  <value>50</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.maximum-capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.accessible-node-labels</name> 
  <value>online</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.accessible-node-labels.online.capacity</name> 
  <value>100</value>
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.accessible-node-labels.stream.capacity</name> 
  <value>0</value>
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.default-node-label-expression</name> 
  <value>online</value> 
</property>

</configuration>
```

When I run applications submitting on onlineQ queue, it just uses resources from online-labeled nodes. In situations nodes with `stream` label are down (meaning just 3 node manager with label `online` are running), I encountered with some inconsistency in YARN JMX server data, where it shows:

**root queue data:**

```
{
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=ResourceManager,name=QueueMetrics,q0=root",
    "modelerType" : "QueueMetrics,q0=root",
    "tag.Queue" : "root",
    "tag.Context" : "yarn",
    "tag.Hostname" : "namenode",
    "AvailableMB" : 3072,
    "AvailableVCores" : 3,
  }
```

**streamQ data:**

```
{
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=ResourceManager,name=QueueMetrics,q0=root,q1=streamQ",
    "modelerType" : "QueueMetrics,q0=root,q1=streamQ",
    "tag.Queue" : "root.streamQ",
    "tag.Context" : "yarn",
    "tag.Hostname" : "namenode",
    "AvailableMB" : 1536,
    "AvailableVCores" : 1,
  }
```

**onlineQ data:**

```
{
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=ResourceManager,name=QueueMetrics,q0=root,q1=onlineQ",
    "modelerType" : "QueueMetrics,q0=root,q1=onlineQ",
    "tag.Queue" : "root.onlineQ",
    "tag.Context" : "yarn",
    "tag.Hostname" : "namenode",
    "AvailableMB" : 1536,
    "AvailableVCores" : 1,
  }
```

The problem is in `AvailableMB` and `AvailableVCores`. The root queue data is as desired, but I expected in `streamQ` queue, resources be zero and in `onlineQ` queue, resources be 3072MB and 3 core. But it's not! That's because properties:

```
<property> 
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.streamQ.capacity</name> 
<value>50</value> 
</property>

<property> 
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.onlineQ.capacity</name> 
<value>50</value> 
</property>
```

But this should only apply to resources of nodes without a label (which are in default_partition)! What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved after I change the Hadoop version from `2.7.5` to `2.8.3`.